# Oauth2 protected resource

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

It seems the book that I'm following has a few errors - getting an exception when I run the App.  According to the manual, all that is required is the following setup for oauth2 resource protection. I followed each step verbatim but I'm getting the following exception when I start the server and go to url (as stated):

`http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientapp&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/callback&response_type=code&scope=read_profile`

Exception

```
rg.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:138)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Configuration Class(s)

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("clientapp").secret("123456")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:9000/callback")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("read_profile", "read_contacts");
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("clientapp").secret("123456")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:9000/callback")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("read_profile", "read_contacts");
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

}
```

application.properties

```
security.user.name=foo
security.user.password=123
```

pom

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.packt.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-code-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>auth-code-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: How did you POST your username/password?

Comment: i placed user/pass inside the application.properties as you at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not configured login for your authorization in you web. You'll need security config class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and override `configure` method to enable login.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
..
..
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http 
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
}
..
..
}
```

You'll be redirected to login page. Here's an example of what I did [sometime back.](https://github.com/anealkeshi/springboot-microservices/blob/master/authentication-service/src/main/java/me/anilkc/config/WebSecurityConfig.java)

**Update:**

Update your **application.properties** file. You have wrong properties to override username and password. It should be

```
spring.security.user.name=foo
spring.security.user.password=123
```

Comment: see the edit. you don't have `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configured, at least in your post.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't accept? Did you see login page or see an error?

Comment: i'm redirect to the login page but does not accept the credentials besides the manual does not mention anything about configuring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: .ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER is probably deprecated. Only options are : BASIC_AUTH_ORDER and DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER

Comment: I'm not sure we need WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter becuase the manual doesn't mention it. It does mention the annotation '@EnableAuthorizationServer - "By adding the '@EnableAuthorizationServer annotation, we are importing some important configuration classes which are AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration and AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration. The AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration class, has an important dependency for an OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server to work."

Comment: You'll need `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in-order to authenticate. `@EnableAuthorizationServer` will enable authorization but not authentication (http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html#configuring-the-endpoint-urls). The update above works and I verified with your configuration.